# I saved the audio file which i got from a response, but it doesnt play

Tags: node.js, audio, filesystems

I am using a text-to-speech API. On postman, when I directly call the API, I can play the returned audio file in postman. But When I call the API through my node server and save it, the file doesnt play.

I tried saving the file in both `mp3` and `mpeg` but both couldnt be played.

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  req.on("data", (data, err) => {
    let body = JSON.parse(data);
    body = querystring.stringify(body);
    request(
      {
        headers: {
          "X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY-ID": "123123",//dummy variable
          "X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY": "123123",//dummy variable
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        uri: "https://naveropenapi.apigw.ntruss.com/voice/v1/tts",
        timeout: 100000,
        method: "POST",
        body
      },
      (err, response, body) => {
        console.log(body);
        if (err) res.status(400).send(err);
        else {
          fs.writeFile("./src/temp/file.mpeg", body, err => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.status(200).send("success");
          });
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Here is the postman inputs and result(headers are equivalent to the code above):
KEY-ID`,`clientSecret`

[image]
The code did save a `file.mpeg` in the correct directory, but the audio cannot be played.

Below is the `console.log(body)`. As you can see something is broken.
[image]

If I replace `body = querystring.stringify(body)` with `let {body} = req`, I get the following error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:595
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:595:11)
    at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:567:10)
    at Request.write (C:\Users\Sihoon Kim\Desktop\development\ZEPETO\node_modules\request\request.js:1500:27)
    at end (C:\Users\Sihoon Kim\Desktop\development\ZEPETO\node_modules\request\request.js:549:18)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sihoon Kim\Desktop\development\ZEPETO\node_modules\request\request.js:578:7)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

Comment: CAn you show up request in postman?
I think we don't need `body = querystring.stringify(body);`

Comment: if i remove that part there is no response at all. The response seems correct because on return header there are information such as `Content-Type:audio/mpeg`, `Content-Length:8100`

Comment: Can you show postman request and `console.log` your `body` variable?

Comment: added postman request, and console.log(body)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this. Or is this just a limitation on postman?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: unfortunately I didnt continue with this. I was coding this in a hackathon, so we went for a completely different approach